# Squared Quaternion using AVX

Tags: optimization, vectorization, quaternions, avx

Does any one know how to vectorize this function using AVX

```
void cuadradoYSumaNormal(quaternion* a, quaternion* b, quaternion* c) {
          c->w = a->w*a->w - a->x*a->x - a->y*a->y - a->z*a->z + b->w;
          c->x = 2.*a->w*a->x + b->x;
          c->y = 2.*a->w*a->y + b->y;
          c->z = 2.*a->w*a->z + b->z;
    }
```

I can assume unit-length for a, b and c

`quaternion` is the following struct:

```
struct quaternion{
  double w;
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};
```

What the function must do is to square the quaternion `*a` (using quaterninon multiplication rules) then add the quaternion `*b` and store the result in `*c`.

Comment: I do not think this is possible to do that much more efficiently than this scalar code. Indeed, 1. you work on only 3x4 double values and AVX instructions have a quite high latency; 2. the code is not SIMD-friendly (vectorizing this code will probably require vperm/extract instructions which have a high latency). Do you plan to work on more quaternion (eg. arrays) ?

Comment: I guess you can't assume unit-length of `*a`? Do you aim for high throughput or low latency? (Btw: if possible, provide code which compiles without warnings ...)

Comment: If you want this to not suck, do four `cuadradoYSumaNormal` operations in parallel on 4 separate quaternions, like `a.x[i + 0..3]`.  So you'll have vectors of four `x`, four `y`, and so on, and everything is purely "vertical" SIMD with the same sequence of operations as the scalar source.  See [Slides + text: SIMD at Insomniac Games (GDC 2015)](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/) for more about why using a SIMD vector to hold one geometry vector or quaternion is bad for SIMD.

Comment: Also, your function should be `void` because it doesn't return a value.

Comment: If `a` has unit length, you can rewrite this as `2*a.w * a + b - [1,0,0,0]`.

Answer (score 4):

This solution works in case `a` has unit length, i.e., `aw^2+ax^2+ay^2+az^2 == 1`

In that case, the calculation of `c->w` is equivalent to calculating `2*a->w*a->w  - 1.0 + b->w`, making this far easier to vectorize. Multiplication with 2 can be achieved by adding `a` (or `a->w`) to itself. To reduce the latency chain, the `-1.0` should be added to `b->w`. Possible implementation:

```
inline __m256d unit(double value = 1.0)
{
    return _mm256_set_pd(0,0,0,value);
}

void cuadradoYSumaNormal_avx(quaternion* a, quaternion* b, quaternion* c) {

    __m256d aw = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&a->w);
    __m256d a_ = _mm256_loadu_pd(&a->w);
    __m256d b_ = _mm256_loadu_pd(&b->w);

    __m256d a_squared_plus_one = _mm256_mul_pd(aw, _mm256_add_pd(a_,a_));
    __m256d c_ = _mm256_add_pd(a_squared_plus_one, _mm256_add_pd(b_, unit(-1.0)));

    _mm256_storeu_pd(&c->w, c_);
}
```

If besides AVX you have FMA available, you can join some additions and multiplications to

```
(aw * a + [-0.5,0,0,0]) * 2.0 + b
```

Resulting in just two FMAs (and one broadcast and some loads). Possible implementation:

```
void cuadradoYSumaNormal_fma(quaternion* a, quaternion* b, quaternion* c) {

    __m256d aw = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&a->w);
    __m256d a_ = _mm256_loadu_pd(&a->w);
    __m256d b_ = _mm256_loadu_pd(&b->w);

    __m256d a_squared_half = _mm256_fmadd_pd(aw, a_, unit(-0.5));
    __m256d c_ = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a_squared_half, _mm256_set1_pd(2.0), b_);

    _mm256_storeu_pd(&c->w, c_);
}
```